# How can I add Froakie to my pokedex?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I started with Fennikin and finished the game but I guess I never saw Froakie. His second and third evolved forms I have in my pokedex.

I know that people can show you a pokemon that will be added to your pokedex.

How can I find Froakie in order to get him over a trade through the GTS?

Comment: If you scroll to the bottom of the GTS alphabet list, @Kecoey, then you'll see an option to type in the name of the Pokemon. I believe it reads "What Pokemon?"

Comment: @Kendra Thanks! That pretty much completely answers my question. But also all of the ones that I looked up in that way were looking for legiondaries to trade, which wasn't the case for any other pokemon I have searched for.

Comment: That's just player preference. I can't help you with that.

Comment: I know but it seems extremely suspect that it was LITERALLY every single trade for Froakie. Not a single one was not looking for a legendary to trade. I don't know it was probably m connection or something weird going on

Comment: @Kecoey - catch a female eevee, put it up on GTS and ask for froakie. You'll get one pretty quick